# Cannot find module 'firebase-admin' from 'index.cjs.js'

Tags: firebase, testing

I was using `@firebase/testing` on Jest, but since [it's deprecated and instructed to use new one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/testing), I decided to move to `@firebase/rules-unit-testing`.

Here is the code where I just switched them.

```js
import { initializeAdminApp } from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import "babel-polyfill";

it("is ok", async () => {
  const admin = initializeAdminApp({ projectId: "my-project" });

  try {
    const doc = admin.firestore().collection("items").doc("item-1");
    await doc.set({ name: "Item 1" });
    const ss = await doc.get();
    expect(ss.data()?.name).toBe("Item 1");
  } finally {
    await admin.delete();
  }
});
```

When I run this test with emu, it results "Cannot find module 'firebase-admin' from 'index.cjs.js'" error.

```
Cannot find module 'firebase-admin' from 'index.cjs.js'                      
                                                                                              
      3 |                                       
      4 | it("is ok", async () => {                                                              
    > 5 |   const admin = initializeAdminApp({ projectId: "my-project" });                           
        |                 ^
```

It passes if it is the old `@firebase/testing`.

What did I miss?

- Node.js v14.8.0
- Jest 25.5.4
- firebase 7.21.1
- firebase-tools 8.11.2
- @firebase/testing 0.20.11
- @firebase/rules-unit-testing 1.0.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `firebase-admin` is an npm package. Just installed it and all worked.

```
$ npm install -D firebase-admin
```

Comment: This should really be documented! Thanks you saved my butt!

Comment: Why -D option ?? this dependency will be needed in production in most cases, so like officially recommended :  npm i firebase-admin is the good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I started to use **firebase-admin@^10.0.1** and I had this error when running **jest** tests. It couldn't map "firebase-admin/app" to "firebase-admin/lib/app" as expected. So I have mapped this manually on **jest.config.ts**:

```
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json';

...
export default {
 ...
 moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(
    {
      ...compilerOptions.paths,
      'firebase-admin/*': ['node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/*'],
    },
    {
      prefix: '<rootDir>',
    },
  ),
...
}
```

That worked for me.

And just to note, my **tsconfig.json** is like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "modules/*": [
        "src/modules/*"
      ],
      "shared/*": [
        "src/shared/*"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```